# Getting null on Angular Js http post in code-igniter

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am  trying to a user registration using angular js and codeigniter ,but i will get NUll response in `POST` request

```
$scope.signup=function(user){
  $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : baseUrl+'home/user_register',
          data    : $scope.user, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
         })
          .success(function(data) {
              alert(data);
          });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Full name</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.fullName">
  </label>
   ......
.........
```

Serverside

```
public function user_register()
    {
        $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        var_dump($_POST);

    }
```

I am getting `NULL` in `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

You should not post data as `x-www-form-urlencoded` if you want to use it as POST payload in the server. So you should just remove Content-type header:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseUrl + 'home/user_register',
  data: $scope.user
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

However, if you post data as `form-urlencoded` you can still access form data on the server via `$_POST['user']` array.